# Как в input вывести label?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CompanyId, new { data_company_id = string.Empty })
<input type="text" name="name" id="f" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Company")' />
```

В инпут я подтягиваю компанию ajaxом, а  id компании записываю в `@Html.HiddenFor`

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
            var target = $(this);
            target.autocomplete({
                source: target.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    $('input[data-company-id]').val(ui.item.value);

                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

Как подставить Name после выбора, а не id  `<input type="text" name="name" id="f" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Company")' />`) ??

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Антон, посмотрите на свой предыдущий вопрос. Там вы почему-то используете `ui.item.value`, а здесь `ui.value`. Почему?

Comment: Эта проблема решена. Да, сейчас поправлю на `ui.item.value` , но проблема осталась, что автоматом вот сюда ставится id `<input type="text" name="name" id="f" data-autocomplete-source='@Url.Action("GetSearchValue", "Company")' />` А надо Name (label)

Comment: Посмотрите https://jsfiddle.net/gqru5rd3/1/ Обратите внимание на комментарии в коде

Comment: @Dmitry Я переформулировал вопрос в описании.

Comment: Моя ошибка, написал код, не проверив его работоспособность. Немного не так работает *Autocomplete*, как я ожидал

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Вот так все работает как надо

```
public ActionResult GetSearchValue(string term)
        {
            var models = db.Companies.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(term))
                             .Select(a => new
                             {
                                 value = a.Name,
                                 Id = a.Id.ToString(),
                                 label = a.Name
                              }).ToList();
            return Json(models, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[data-autocomplete-source]").each(function () {
            var target = $(this);
            target.autocomplete({
                              select: function (event, ui) {
                   $('input[data-company-id]').val(ui.item.Id);
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```